# How to fix vue Router unknow <router-view> error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">
   
    </div>


<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.vue

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <navigation></navigation>
    
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import router from './router.js';

import navigation from './components/Navigation.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  router,
  components: {
    navigation,
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import navigation from './components/Navigation.vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('navigation',navigation)
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path:'/',
        component:HomePage }
    ]
});

module.exports = router;
```

Navigation.vue

```
<template>
    <nav class="nav-wrapper">
                
        <div class="logo">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 10.935v2.131l-8 3.947v-2.23l5.64-2.783-5.64-2.79v-2.223l8 3.948zm-16 3.848l-5.64-2.783 5.64-2.79v-2.223l-8 3.948v2.131l8 3.947v-2.23zm7.047-10.783h-2.078l-4.011 16h2.073l4.016-16z"/></svg>
            <div class="ml-2">WebDevs</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <div v-for="(item,key) in nav" v-bind:key="key">
                <a :href="item.link" 
                    class="link-item"
                    :class="[ (item.subLinkModal) ? 'link-active' : '' ]"
                    @click="toggleSubModal(item)">
                        {{ item.title }}
                </a>
                
                <template v-if="item.subLinks && item.subLinkModal">
                    <div class="sublinks">
                        <a v-for="(subLink,key) in item.subLinks" v-bind:key="key" :href="subLink.link" class="link-item">{{ subLink.title }}</a>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
            return {
                nav: [
                    { title: 'Home', link: '#home' },
                    { title: 'About', link: '#about', subLinks: [
                        { title: 'History', link: '#history' },
                        { title: 'Our Team', link: '#team' },
                    ], subLinkModal: false },
                    { title: 'Services', link: '#services', subLinks: [
                        { title: 'Audio', link: '#audio' },
                        { title: 'Video', link: '#video' },
                        { title: 'Web', link: '#web' },
                    ], subLinkModal: false },
                ]
            }
        },
        
        methods: {
            toggleSubModal: function (item) {
                if (item.subLinks) {
                    item.subLinkModal = ! item.subLinkModal;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However I got error,

Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

--->  at src/App.vue

and also

main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I guess vue trying to interpret index.html as part of main.js?
how can i fix this?

Comment: Remove `id="app"`, `router`  from **App.vue** and `navigation` from **main.js**

Comment: @Radeanu Thanks but i still got the  error

Comment: Can you show `Navigation.vue` component ?

Comment: @Radeanu i added navigation.vue but it just component

Comment: Use `export default` syntax instead of `module.exports`, check docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html